# Using the latest python version on Raspberry PI

Tags: python, linux, shell, python-2.7, python-3.x

Yesterday I got my Raspberry Pi running Raspbian and now I'm trying to run a python module on, which I created earlier on my Windows PC.

Unfortunately this isn't working: when I go to the python file through the command line and execute it with "python rpserver.py" it gives me an error and states it cannot find the package "socketserver" (even though the file runs without any problem in IDLE on the raspberry pi).
On closer inspection I find out that my Raspberry Pi contains Python 2.6, 2.7, 3 and 3.4. I was told to not uninstall the earlier versions as some components could rely on it. When executing the command python -c "import sys; print sys.path" it shows me all folder of Python 2.7 and not 3.4 which I need.

How can I change the command so that I can run the module from the command line?

Comment: Try `python3` as the command...

Comment: Haha I literally was busy with this for over an hour and you fix it within 2 minutes. Thanks. I guess it didn't work due to lacking backward compatibility of python 3 which is really annoying...